# Some set theory exercises. Need help.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Determine if the equation is true; otherwise, give a counterexample.

$1.\space A \cup ( A \cup B) =A $

My answer : It is not true, my example
$ A \cap ( A \cup B) =A $

$ 2. \space A \cap ( A \cup B) =B $

It is also not true (Only when $ A= B$ ). My example $ B \cap ( A \cup B) =B $

$ 3. \space [(A \subset B) \wedge (C \subset D ] \Rightarrow  [ A \cap C) \subset  
 (B \cap D)] $

I have no idea what I should do. Could you send me some tips on how to do it correctly?

Comment: For the third, notice that $(A\subset B)$ is better thought of as a statement, not a set, and so having an intersection between two statements is ambiguous.  The logical "and", notated as $\wedge$ is used to connect the two rather than a $\cap$.

Answer (score 1):

in the first question you are right in the conclusion but not in the way; a counter-example should show some kind of an example that doesn't correspond with the claim, s.t $A=\{1\}$, $B=\{2\}$, $A \cup B = \{1,2\}$, $A\cup (A\cup B)=\{1,2\} \neq \{1\}=A$

in the second question, again, same thing, the conclusion is correct, but the idea is to give a real example that doesn't correspond, and you can use the same example as before.

the third one i would advise to try several examples like the one i have shown to find the intuition.
good luck!

Comment: The third one must be solve without examples I'm afraid.

Comment: I meant only for the intuition. If you decided to prove then you need to assume that A is a proper subset of B, and as well C is a proper subset of D, and then prove the claim that $A\cap C \subset B \cap D$